# Can someone please tell me the name of this flower??It has sometimes two layers of petals

Tags: identification, flowers, flowering

Its a yellow flower with spiky leaves...Would like to know its name..Some little bigger ones have two layers of petals.

[image]

Comment: Interesting question: yes, an illustration could be helpful, and also the region, and approximate overall size and flower size.

Answer (score 3):

Your bright flower is a variety of Sulfur Cosmos, *Cosmos sulphureus*! They range originally from Southern North America through Northern South America, and have spread to regions all over the world! They are known for attracting butterflies, and have been extensively planted in some regions. There are also different varieties, including some with orange or reddish flowers, and heights ranging from 30cm to 2m! Their flowers may be similar in appearance to other species, however, the leaves of Sulfur Cosmos are quite distinct; their distinctive leaves and their height help when identifying them! The excellent illustration of your Sulfur Cosmos is very helpful!

Comment: This looks to be a correct ID. See here for a photo showing the leaves and flowers: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Cosmos_sulphureus1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

That's not a marigold, its either a Sulphur Cosmos (Cosmos Sulphureus) or Tickseed (Coreopsis Grandiflora/Lanceolata)

Comment: Not either of the coreopsis mentioned - the leaves are not correct for those species.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some marigolds here, yellow ones. In latin they are called *Tagetes*. They like a lot of sun, they seem to look healthy fine so keep treating them like you do now!

Comment: If they're marigolds, then they'll have a distinctive odor when you handle them. So, does that flower kind of stink?